# How can I run python files that I wrote into Pyodides file system?

Tags: javascript, python, ace-editor, pyodide

I am writing a Pyodide based text editor that will run test scripts, when a user types into the editor, using ace-editor, I grab whatever the user types and write it into a python file using pyodides `pyodide.FS.writeFile()` function, I do the same with the premade test file I have, however, I am struggling to understand if pyodide can run the files I write into pyodides virtual file system as I don't see a reason why it shouldnt. Here is the javascript file that handles this below, keep in mind I am using ace:

```js
//fileSaver is used to save the code to a file and download it 
const fileSaver = require('file-saver');
// Setup ace variables and the output pane for pyodide
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var output_pane;
// The following line will essentially be the "file path" input for the RST directive, or 
// we can figure out how to pass arguments into an iframe if thats even possible
var testFilePath = '/_static/test_files/test.py';

loadPyodide().then((pyodide) => {
    // pyodide is now ready to use...
    globalThis.pyodide = pyodide;
    appendOutput('Python ready.\n');
});

function appendOutput(msg) {
    // used to add program output to the textarea
    output_pane.value = output_pane.value + '\n' + msg;
    output_pane.scrollTop = output_pane.scrollHeight;
}

function configEditor(){
    // configure the ace editor to make it usable
    editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/python");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setBehavioursEnabled(true);
    editor.setFontSize(13);
    //Fix indentation issue with ace editor, not really the best solution but it works
    var code = editor.getValue();
    var lines = code.split("\n");
    var minIndent = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        if (line.trim().length > 0) {
            var indent = line.search(/\S/);
            if (minIndent === null || (indent !== -1 && indent < minIndent)) {
                minIndent = indent;
            }
        }
    }
    if (minIndent !== null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i].trim().length > 0) {
                lines[i] = lines[i].slice(minIndent);
            }
        }
        code = lines.join('\n');
        editor.setValue(code);
    }
}

function openCode(filePathToUse) {
    getCode(filePathToUse)
      .then(code => {
        var modelist = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist");
        var modeName = modelist.getModeForPath(filePathToUse).mode;
        editor.session.setMode(modeName);
        editor.session.setValue(code);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error occurred while opening the code:', error);
      });
  }

async function runCode(code_to_run) {
    // Run the code thats within the editor so students can test
    if(code_to_run == editor.getValue()){
        console.logs = [];

        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            window.pyodide.runPython(code_to_run)
            resolve(true)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
        });
    
        let result = await promise;
        if (result) { 
            appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
        }
    } else {
        // run the code from the editor and display the output in the textarea

        let data = editor.getValue(); 
        let testData = code_to_run;
        window.pyodide.FS.writeFile("/challenge.py", data);
        window.pyodide.FS.writeFile("/test.py", testData);
        let challengeFile = pyodide.FS.readFile("/challenge.py");
        let testFile = pyodide.FS.readFile("/test.py");
        console.log(challengeFile);
        console.log(testFile);
        
        console.logs = [];

        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            window.pyodide.runPython(testCodeString)
            resolve(true)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
        });

        let result = await promise;
        if (result) { 
            appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
        }
    }
}

function saveCode(code) {
    var blob = new Blob([code], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
    window.saveAs(blob, 'challenge.py');
}

//make a function getCode that takes in a file path and returns the code in that file as a string to use in ace
async function getCode(codeToGet) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(codeToGet);
      const data = await response.text();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred while opening the code:', error);
    }
  }


//codeToSwitch will be a file path
function switchFile(codeToSwitch) {
    getCode(codeToSwitch)
    .then(code => {
        var EditSession = ace.require("ace/edit_session").EditSession;
        var oldSession = editor.getSession();
        //change to new file
        var newSession = new EditSession(code, "ace/mode/python");
        editor.setSession(newSession);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error occurred while opening the code:', error);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    output_pane = document.getElementById("output");
    // Add event listeners for downloading code
    document.getElementById("downloadButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
        saveCode(editor.getValue());
    });

    // Add event listeners for switching files
    document.getElementById("switchButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
        switchFile(testFilePath);
    });

    document.getElementById("runButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
        runCode(editor.getValue());
    });
    
    // Add event listeners for running code
    document.getElementById("run_code").addEventListener('click', function () {
        //Run the getcode function to get the code from the editor
        getCode(testFilePath)
        .then(code => {
            runCode(code);
        }) 
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error occurred while opening the code:', error);
        });
    });

    // Capture the output from Pyodide and add it to an array
    console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
    console.logs = [];
    console.log = function(){
        console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
        console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    
    configEditor();
});
```

The main thing to pay attention to is the `runCode()` function as that is where the changes should be made. I first grab whatever the user wrote, put it into pyodides virtual file system, do the same with a premade test file, then in the variable `testCodeString` I want to just run the test file. I tried `import test` but that didnt work. How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say `import test` doesn't work, what do you mean?  Did you do `pyodide.runPython('import test')`, and if so, what happened? An error, nothing at all?

Comment: @JeffGlass I had tried the runPython bit you just typed, when doing so it just dosent run the main and can only execute it once

Comment: For sure - to be clear, I wasn't proposing that as a solution, I was just wondering what happened when you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into how Pyodide handles packages, local files can be written to the file system to be run by using the `exec` keyword, however, to ensure that test output will change when editing code, then you need to clear `sys.modules` like so in the code:

```js
console.logs = [];

var data = editor.getValue(); 
var testData = code_to_run;
window.pyodide.FS.writeFile("challenge.py", data);
window.pyodide.FS.writeFile("test.py", testData);
        
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.pyodide.runPython(`
        exec(open('test.py').read())
        import sys
        sys.modules.pop("challenge", None)
        sys.modules.pop("test", None)
`)
resolve(true)
   }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
   });
        
let result = await promise;
if (result) { 
    appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
}
```